# Deserialize XML containing Properties and Values with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xmlmapper

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML.

```
<RESPONSE>
    <FIELDS>
        <FIELD KEY="MSG_VERSION">003</FIELD>
        <FIELD KEY="CUSTOMER_NBR">001</FIELD>
        ...
        <FIELD KEY="ORIGINAL_TYPE">RM1</FIELD>
    </FIELDS>
</RESPONSE>
```

I need to capture the values from `KEY` properties and the values. Following is the Java class I have created.

```
package io.app.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlText;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "RESPONSE")
public class ResponseData {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "FIELDS")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "FIELD")
    private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    @Data
    public static class Field {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String key;
        @JacksonXmlText(value = true)
        private String content;
    }
}
```

The `XmlMapper` has been initialized as follows.

```
private final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

The issue is that, although the `content` is properly getting set, the `key` value is always `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be a case of case-differences, i.e. the field `key` might be interpreted as attribute `Key` which is different from `KEY`.

Comment: @Thomas that was exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas pointed out in a comment on the post, it was the case of the property that was causing the issue.

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "KEY")
private String key;
```

This was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have like below. (I haven't tried). More readable.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "RESPONSE")
class ResponseFields {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "FIELDS")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private Fields[] fields;

    //getters, setters, toString
}


class Fields {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "FIELD")
    private Field[] field;

    //getters, setters, toString
}

class Field {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String key;
    @JacksonXmlText(value = true)
    private String value;

    //getters, setters, toString
}
```

And then;

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
ResponseFields responseFields = mapper.readValue(XML, ResponseFields.class);
System.out.println(responseFields);
```